# NSE: file update notification

Tags: explorer, windows-shell, shell32

I have the question. I have designed namespace extension (NSE). My NSE provides files with theur PIDLs. I store in the PIDL various information. Something has happened and PIDL of the file is changed, but name is left old. Old PIDL is invalid and new PIDL is valid. How should I notify explorer about these changes? Function SHChangeNotify() notifies explorer about such things. It seems that only SHCNE_RENAMEITEM flag allows old and new PIDLs in the SHChangeNotify() call. But name of file is not changed!